# Can you unlock a Issuing wallet if the Distribution wallet also signed the lock transaction?

Tags: assets, wallets

We have a unique use case for the blockchain and are run into a tricky situation when it comes to using the wallets securely as Stellar recommends to mint and issue digital assets (two wallet structure and to lock the `ISSUING` wallet to prevent from further minting of an asset). After we are finished with the assets, we want to send them all back to the `ISSUING` wallet to close the asset and merge both wallets back to our master "OG" wallet that created them.  Solely to reclaim the 2XLM reserves.

The main question is: Can you unlock a wallet at all?

Possible idea:

`IF` the `DISTRIBUTION` wallet signed the transaction when the `ISSUING` wallet was locked, could it be used to unlock it?

If not how can we use the wallets in a secure way as to not allow the issuing of more assets, but reclaim the reserve XLM's?

Answer (score 0):

After testing our theory of using the `DISTIRBUTION` as a multiSignature, we found it works, kind of.  Doesn't fully lock the `ISSUING` wallet but at least it hands over control to the `DISTRIBUTION` wallet.